# What is faster? Map get() or Array find()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Im working with javascript but maybe there is also an general answer.

Assuming we have 10 objects with ids.
Would it be faster to search for an object with an specific id by using the array find() methode:

`const found = entries.find(entries => entries.id === myId)`

or initial collect the data in a Map and use the `get()` methode?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: when you collect the data in map you will iterate over it which will be equal to looping with find so `get` will be slower in that case

however if you want to make various `get` call then it will be faster as you will not have to loop again and again using `find`

Comment: "*Assuming we have 10 objects with ids.*" then it's exceptionally likely that a performance difference, if any, does not matter and might not even be measurable.

Comment: If you are using this inside another loop, use a `Map` object which maps the id to the object. But, that doesn't make much of difference if there are 10 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I know now:

Array.find() is similar iterating/looping through an array and that means, it is slower then using get(), which is not a loop.

So if I want to search only one time in this array, find() should be enough. If I want to find multiple elements in that array. It makes sense to generate a Map from that array.

PS: The amount of 10 was an example. I just wanted to know what generally is faster.

Comment: "*The amount of 10 was an example. I just wanted to know what generally is faster.*" There is still not a general answer. For 10 items a straight `.find()` with `O(n)` complexity might be faster than a `.get()`. A map will have to derive the lookup for the key and fetch an item that belongs with it. Even if it's `O(1)` constant time, it might be a constant 0.01ms vs a loop taking 0.001ms per item. Then for 10 items *at worse* it would take the same time a map would take. Yet when looking up anything but the last item, the linear scan will be faster. Lesson: be careful with "generally".